# Load HTML code from a file in a variable inside JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

PhoneGap app loads an external page in inAppBrowser and injects a bottom bar in that page using executeScript(), so I can have a bar with basic controls on that particular page. That I managed to make work.

However I would love to have this bar (basically a portion of HTML code) be dynamically loaded so I can easily add more/edit templates.

So it goes like this in the index.html file of my test project I am playing with:

```
function injectDatBloodyCode() {
  iabRef.executeScript({
    file: "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"
  }, function(){
    iabRef.executeScript({
      file: "http://blablabla.com/news-app/myScript.js"
    });
  });
}
```

Which loads jQuery first and then my JS file. And here is what I do in this JS:

```
cuckoo = document.createElement("div");
cuckoo.innerHTML = '<div id="cuckoo-child" style="width:100%;height:40px;background-color:#00ff00;position:fixed;left:0;bottom:0;z-index:32000!important""> \
Two gentlemen entering bottom bar... \
</div>';
$('body').appendChild(cuckoo);
```

The goal is to be able to keep #cuckoo-child somewhere in the internal folder (how to turn to it then, btw?) or on a server so I can have easily manageable html code instead of string in quotes even completion hints don't work with. How should I attack this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the content dynamc? if not, have you thought about using a template engine that runs before the html is generated?  Using grunt or gulp you can easily accomplish this with Jade, or Pug.

Comment: Content is mostly static. Grunt, gulp, jade, pug — my vocabulary will become richer today. Thank you, I will look it up!

Comment: Those tools are unnecessary for this simple task.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate out the HTML for `#cuckoo-child` in a file, let's say `bar.html`. Then, include that on the page using a script, let's say `bar.js`:

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    url: 'path/to/bar.html',

    success: function(barHTMLString) {
        // do something with barHTMLString
        $(document.body).prepend(barHTMLString);
    }
});
```

This JS gets the contents of `bar.html` synchronously, which can then be used. If you'd like it to be asynchronous, just remove the `async: false` line.

Comment: I tried ajax requests several times with no luck. Copied yours now, didn't work. Then I added alert("Penetrated!"); in success, but it didn't appear. Problem could be that my url is like "http://blablabla.com/news-app/bottom_bar.html". I use this one, not the local one, because the local didn't work for a some reason, I mean file:///android_assets/www/.

Comment: AJAX does not work on `file:///` protocol for security reasons. You need a HTTP server to test it. This is the one that I use: https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server Just install Node.js, and run `npm install http-server -g` on the command line. To start the server, run `http-server` in the root directory of the project.